# how to handle windows popups using jmeter?

Tags: jmeter

please guide me how to handle windows popups using jmeter.
Whether jmeter can handle windows based alerts or not.
I have tried to google it, but couldnt found.
Thanks

Comment: What kind of application you are testing and which sampler you are using? Ideally if the popups are client centric and not making any interaction with server then most likely it will not be captured in a jmeter script.

Comment: thank you so much for your reply. But how can we make it clear whether it is client centric and making any interaction with server?

Comment: if it's a web application with the help of developer tools you can find out whether it's making any interaction with server or not

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what popups do you see.

If it is JavaScript alert like:

[image: JavaScript Alert]

You shouldn't be worrying about it as JMeter doesn't execute client-side JavaScript however it's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder) proxy is capable of recording and replaying associated requests (if any)

If it is modal dialog like:

[image: Modal alert]

It means that your application uses external authentication provider, i.e.:

- [Basic HTTP Authentication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication)
- [NTLM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NT_LAN_Manager)
- [Kerberos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerberos_(protocol))

All thee above types can be handled by JMeter's [HTTP Authorization Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Authorization_Manager). See the following reference articles:

- [How to Use HTTP Basic Authentication in JMeter](https://blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-http-basic-authentication-jmeter)
- [Windows Authentication with Apache JMeter](https://blazemeter.com/blog/windows-authentication-apache-jmeter)

Comment: Thank you so much.It helped me a lot but if it is a web page dialogue box so how to capture that as when I am trying to capture it using jmeter it is throwing 404  error in jmeter.