# Jmeter - error message "500/unexpected alert open"

Tags: jmeter

I can't close an alert with Jmeter on my website.
Jmeter return me the following message : "500/unexpected alert open".

I tried a lot of methods and I investigated a lot on internet, but I haven't found a solution :(

please, help...

Comment: This is way to vague to even start thinking about a solution.

Comment: when I click on a button on my website, an alert appeared with 2 choice : "OK" or "CANCEL". And I haven't any control on this alert with Jmeter. When I work with selenium I do like that Driver.SwitchTo().Alert().Accept() and it work. But with Jmeter it,s not the case...

Comment: It would improve your question if you would add what you tried yourself. What failed and what you're actually trying to achieve. That said: Jmeter doesn't work the same as a 'normal' user in the sense that it doesn't execute client side code (e.g. what happens in your browser). I don't know your use case, but in most you wouldn't need to interact in that sense. Have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36907636/how-to-handle-windows-popups-using-jmeter. But maybe [this](http://www.jmeter4u.com/2015/06/integrating-selenium-with-jmeter-for.html) can be of use?

Comment: Hello, any feedback on answer ? If ok it should be marked as OK and upvoted so that others can use it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

JMeter is not a browser, as such it doesn't interpret client javascript as Selenium does it.

So you need to understand what Javascript does in terms of request(s) going to server and reproduce this with HTTP Request

Answer (score 0):

Finally I have found a solution to my problem with the following command :

WDS.browser.executeScript('window.onbeforeunload = null;')